# TypeScript bindings for google web signin

Tags: typescript, angular, google-signin, google-oauth, tsd

I'm building an angular2/typescript app. I see that google put out [platform.js](https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js) which gives access to the gapi var as shown here on the [google signin for websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). That works great, but I am having a lot of trouble getting that into typescript.

TS relies on .d.ts files to import javascript. Are there any typescript bindings for the new gapi that google put out? There is this version of gapi from [DefinitelyTyped/gapi](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/gapi), but it is outdated.

I've considered writing my own typings definition for the google js, but I can only find the minified version that google put up.

If there are no tsd bindings for the new google signin, how can I still use this with typescript? I was trying to just save the js file to my local, and do something like 

`var gapi = require('../../js/lib/gapi');`

but that wasn't working out for me, no matter how I tried to import using javascript.

Comment: Similar question answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846232/how-to-implement-signin-with-google-in-angularjs-2-using-typescript/41538969#41538969

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking through the wrong typings on DefinitelyTyped. Somehow I missed [DefinitelyTyped/gapi.auth2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2.d.ts). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to this question and your answer I was able to answer this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39770500/2308745