# How to implement SignIn with Google in Angular 2 using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, google-signin

I have been trying to implement sign in with Google in angular 2 in a separate login component. I am unable to implement it with the documentation available in Google https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Google sign in does work when I declare my script tags and google callback function inside my index.html file. But I require a separate component to be able to render the sign in with google button and receive the callback in it to further process the access token which is received for a user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign-In for Websites and Angular 2 using Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530483/google-sign-in-for-websites-and-angular-2-using-typescript)

Comment: Another shorter solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880243/implementing-google-sign-in-button-in-angular2

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Add this line in your app `index.html` file

### INDEX.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

### Component.ts file

```
declare const gapi: any;
  public auth2: any;
  public googleInit() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    });
  }
  public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (googleUser) => {

        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        //YOUR CODE HERE


      }, (error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });
  }

ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.googleInit();
}
```

### Template html file

```
<button id="googleBtn">Google</button>
```

View the demo on [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/n0pFS3y74EpJzwgscrBu/)

Comment: You have helped me greatly by introducing me on how to access the component object within the callback. Using 'this' was not working... But using 'that' is the answer!

Comment: Thanks :) Quaffer and @Steel for your extra input.

Comment: btw. there is no angularJS 2. There is Angular which is Angular 2+, and there is AngularJS which is Angular below 2

Comment: Right..AngularJS is JavaScript based and Angular2+ is Typescript

Comment: Hi Pravesh ,your code works fine but i am getting the error as 'popup closed by the user'.So I am not able to get the response.Can you suggest any help.

Comment: your code works fine. But after login i want to redirect on home page. how do i achieve this.  CODE::> this._router.navigate(['/home']); // not working

Comment: having same issue than @MMR

Comment: The is one thing that I still can't figure out. All Goole OAuth-Angular examples uses gapi dirrectly. `<div class='g-signin2' data-onsuccess='onSignIn' />` is no longer used and no longer works. (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)
I'm still trying to avoid using gapi dirrectly and can't figure out how to specify onSignIn handler in ts files that will be triggered. If I do this in additional asset/client.js file (without angular) - this works fine

Comment: This post helped me a lot but I would like to add something. Sine we use attachClickHandler and we are out of the ngZone I faced several issues with the update of the UI.
This is why I had to use the following code in order to update the UI accordingly:
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone
                ) {
....
        this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
            (googleUser) => {
                this._ngZone.run(() => {
.....

Comment: This code works, but the button is dead if user clicks back in browser or during some other routing issues.

Comment: Sorry I missed the point in last post: after user browses application, during routing wierd stuff happens, he is either not redirected, or app waits for minutes before redirecting him.. etc. I had same issue when implementing FB login, and I solved it with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-facebook. I need to find corresponding solution for Google OAuth

Comment: hi Pravesh Khatana, I am getting error message after using this code "Invalid cookiePolicy". You have any idea to fix it?

Comment: Hi,
It looks like cookiepolicy doesn't work but cookie_policy.

Comment: And I am getting an error,
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

Comment: I have the same issue "Cannot read property 'load' of undefined". It looks like the platform.js is not loaded by the time ngAfterViewInit() because it is "async defer". I suggest removing those properties from <script> declaration. Honestly i don't know how it worked for someone, because in google examples with plain js you set a callback with your initilization which is called when the script is loaded so you are sure the gapi object existis

Comment: That's Work for me.

Answer (score 19):

### src/index.html

In the index.html file of your app you need to add this in the `<head>` section:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

---

### typings/browser/ambient/gapi/

You need to add [gapi](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi) & [gapi.auth2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gapi.auth2) to your typings:

```
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
npm install --save @types/gapi
```

(see this [borysn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2276284)'s [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526281/typescript-bindings-for-google-web-signin) to understand this a little better).

### src/app/+login/login.component.ts

This is the file of my component, here you need to use the `ngAfterViewInit()` to use the gapi an get the auth. And you can follow the implementation here [developers.google...sign-in/web/build-button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button)

As an example, this is my template:

```html
<div id="my-signin2"></div>
```

and sign in function:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'light',
        'onsuccess': param => this.onSignIn(param)
    });
}

public onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var user : User = new User();

    ((u, p) => {
        u.id            = p.getId();
        u.name          = p.getName();
        u.email         = p.getEmail();
        u.imageUrl      = p.getImageUrl();
        u.givenName     = p.getGivenName();
        u.familyName    = p.getFamilyName();
    })(user, googleUser.getBasicProfile());

    ((u, r) => {
        u.token         = r.id_token;
    })(user, googleUser.getAuthResponse());

    user.save();
    this.goHome();
};
```

**UPDATE:** After some time, and taking in consideration the comments, this answer needed a small update.

Comment: You can also use 

`npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2`
`npm install --save @types/gapi`

Instead of manually adding the namespaces to your typings

I don't know if this is what you meant, I'm just starting with typescript and angular and found this way of adding types

Comment: I played with that example and realized that `(data-onsuccess)="onSignIn"` in the template is not used. Registering the callback is done in `ngAfterViewInit`.

The callback does not trigger the rerendering of the template anyways (I was additionally printing the logged in profile in the template), because the call happens outside of Angular zone. Make sure to inject NgZone and wrap the updates with with `zone.run(() => { /* Updates here  */})`.

Comment: This will never get fired `(data-onsuccess)="onSignIn"` If anyone got it to work, I would be happy to read the implementation. Thanks.

Comment: What if I don't want to add the googleClientId in the meta tag?

Comment: @Smit, public googleClientId is safe and efficient practice. If you want to hide it for some reason, you have to delegate authentication communication back to your sever, adding more requests and delays. With public googleClientId all this job is done between client browser and google api without involving your server at all. Only your guarded API calls would pass the JWT token and server can validate it (also without extra communication to google).

Answer (score 16):

Lexical scoping with an arrow (`=>`) function makes the use of `let that = this;` unnecessary.

A *cleaner* version of Pravesh's example, *without the need for the `that` scoping work-around*, would be:

**Index.html**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

**Component.ts**

```
declare const gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'google-signin',
  template: '<button id="googleBtn">Google Sign-In</button>'
})
export class GoogleSigninComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private clientId:string = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  private scope = [
    'profile',
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
  ].join(' ');

  public auth2: any;

  public googleInit() {        
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: this.clientId,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: this.scope
      });
      this.attachSignin(this.element.nativeElement.firstChild);
    });
  }

  public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (googleUser) => {
        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        // ...
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    console.log('ElementRef: ', this.element);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.googleInit();
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div id="googleBtn">Google</div>
```

[Working Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fWU8Yn3maOMCTyKIXWFl?p=preview)

Comment: this seems to be a cleaner approach as per ng2

Comment: hi Steve Gomez, I am getting error message after using this code "Invalid cookiePolicy". You have any idea to fix it?

Comment: hi Steve Gomez, I am getting error message "Invalid cookiePolicy". You have any idea to fix it?

Comment: @SandipMoradiya their api changed from cookiepolicy to cookie_policy

Answer (score 8):

There is also another way to connect with google :

Add theses lines in the **index.html** :

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR-GOOGLE-APP-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

and then here is a sample code to write on a component (or a service if you want) :

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
declare const gapi : any;


@Component({ ... })
export class ComponentClass {
   constructor() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function () {
         gapi.auth2.init()
      });
   }

   googleLogin() {
      let googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      googleAuth.then(() => {
         googleAuth.signIn({scope: 'profile email'}).then(googleUser => {
            console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile());
         });
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> As of now, the angular latest version came and mostly we are using angular 4/5/6, so thought to give this simple solution to login by social so someone who really want it

***Angular 4/5/6 Social Login***

In your AppModule, import the SocialLoginModule

```
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider, LinkedInLoginProvider} from "angularx-social-login";


let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
  {
    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("Google-OAuth-Client-Id")
  },
  {
    id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("Facebook-App-Id")
  },
  {
    id: LinkedInLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("LinkedIn-client-Id", false, 'en_US')
  }
]);

export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: provideConfig
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And use it in your components

by importing below modules

```
import { AuthService } from "angularx-social-login";
import { SocialUser } from "angularx-social-login";
```

For complete reference you can look their [Github](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login)

it has really simple page for [demo](https://abacritt.github.io/angularx-social-login/)

Comment: Only this solution worked with Angular 6 with npm package angular5-social-login

Comment: I have implemented the above and its working fine. I need to call https://accounts.google.com/logout, for logging user out of google completely. Since AuthService will make the instance null and log me just of  the app, my requirement demands logging out of google. How should i achieve the same using the link i have mentioned i.e. https://accounts.google.com/logout

Comment: As we doesn’t have back end service so this service is only manage front end.You can do manually, check the local storage,you’ll get something or use a flag when logged in and save it to local storage and on logged out delete from there.

Comment: How do I implement it if I get "Google-OAuth-Client-Id" dynamically from service? I spent a day trying, but no luck.

Answer (score 7):

pretty much none of this worked for me because I want the google button made by Google. @mathhew eon's code worked but that does not use their button.

so I threw the google data-success function on the window and it works PERFECT! It also has the added advantage of if the user is already logged in it will auto call the googleLogin function.

html

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="googleLogin" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

In your index.html put this in the head:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR-GOOGLE-APP-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email AND WHATEVER OTHER SCOPES YOU WANT">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

then in your ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    (window as any).googleLogin = this.googleLogin
}
public googleLogin(userInfo) {
    console.log(userInfo)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is the same in previous answered except I added

declare var gapi: any; otherwise, you will get the error.

**src/index.html**

In the index.html file of your app you need to add this in the  section:

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

**typings/browser/ambient/gapi/**

You need to add gapi & gapi.auth2 to your typings:

```
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
npm install --save @types/gapi
```

(see this borysn's question to understand this a little better).

**src/app/+login/login.component.ts**

This is the file of my component, here you need to use the ngAfterViewInit() to use the gapi an get the auth. And you can follow the implementation here developers.google...sign-in/web/build-button

As an example, this is my template:

```
<div id="my-signin2"></div>
```

and sign in function:

```
 declare var gapi: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
      'scope': 'profile email',
      'width': 240,
      'height': 50,
      'longtitle': true,
      'theme': 'light',
      'onsuccess': param => this.onSignIn(param)
  });
}

public onSignIn(googleUser) {
   var user : User = new User();

      ((u, p) => {
         u.id            = p.getId();
         u.name          = p.getName();
         u.email         = p.getEmail();
         u.imageUrl      = p.getImageUrl();
         u.givenName     = p.getGivenName();
         u.familyName    = p.getFamilyName();
      })(user, googleUser.getBasicProfile());

      ((u, r) => {
         u.token         = r.id_token;
      })(user, googleUser.getAuthResponse());

      user.save();
      this.goHome();
};
```

Comment: Not everything is the same except gapi. You also added render method on gapi.singin2 which was a saver for me. Thanks.