# Angular 5 Google Signin into component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-signin

I've implemented Client Google Signin using my API Key into my html page. When I insert all the necessay tags and functions into index.html it works perfectly, but when it comes to insert the Google Signin button into a component, it is not even shown.

So, if this is how it works in a simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Google Signin out Demo</title>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer> 
</script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="myprivateid.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>


<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div><br />
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    console.log(profile);
  }

  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I want to insert into an Angular component and leave the things as similar as I can I would left the meta-tag and the google script into the index.html and then insert the button in a component. It is not even shown. What am I getting wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer> 
    </script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="myprivateid.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the specific template of the component in which I want the button to appear I insert:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div><br />
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
```

Apart from the little javascript code I must add, the button is not even shown. 
How can I fix it without installing other npm components?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? It seems that in my case the function onSignIn() callback function is not called.

Comment: @sbattou https://stackoverflow.com/a/40418555/1429439 fixed this issue for me

Comment: @C.M. thank you for getting back to me but I decided to not implement Google+ as it is shutting down soon https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-45792349

Comment: I heard that G+ was shutting down, but I thought this was the JavaScript for any Google account sign in for web apps, not just Google+.