# Google Sign In button doesn't appear in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to add google sign in button in my angular app, but it doesn't appear. It's height is always 0, if I change that - no buton appears. How can I handle that? I thought maybe it's styles issue but I was wrong. I tried to find an answer in SO but didn't found any appropriate solution. I'm new to Angular and need some help, please.

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_ID">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

my login.component.ts is looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    onSignIn(googleUser: any) {
        console.log(googleUser);
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

and login.component.html

```
<div class="login-wrapper" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">

    <mat-card class="box">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>Sign in</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>

        <form class="login-form">
            <mat-card-content>
                <mat-form-field class="login-form_full-width">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Username">
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field class="login-form_full-width">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Password">
                </mat-form-field>
            </mat-card-content>
            <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" class="btn-block">Log in</button>
        </form>
        <div class="g-singin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    </mat-card>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing to init the gapi module, Like this:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    gapi.auth2.init();
});
```

If you still face issue, consider using npm module made for angular :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login

Comment: Where should I add that `gapi.load`? Error in the console says `gapi is not defined`

Comment: You shoud add this at the end of  your `index.html` page under script tag.

Comment: that doesn't help.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880243/google-sign-in-button-in-angular-2. Or the npm package is another option

Comment: I do exactly the same, but my button is not appear. (

Comment: As the currect solution is vannila javascript I would also try to use a npm package, made specially for Angular client:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login