# Google API with angular2 Error:400

Tags: angular, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client, google-api-js-client

I am following this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770500/2983051
but unfortunately I am getting:

> 400. That’s an error. Error: invalid_request Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.

I am running angular2 app locally, in my **gapi credentials**  *Authorised JavaScript origins* and *Authorised redirect URIs* are http://127.0.0.1:4200

Any ideas how to fix it? maybe good links for using angular2 + nodejs with google  oauth2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Good [example is here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow)

I was defining the **Authorized redirect URI**, but for JavaScript API it should stay **undefined**.
[image]