# Angular 2 view not updated after HTTP call

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js

I'm experimenting with Angular 2 and I'm trying to do an http request with the built-in HTTP service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public get(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/endpoint')
               .map((data) => <string[]>data.json()['content']);
    }
}
```

Usage is the following:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public content: string[];

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myService.get().subscribe((data) => {
            this.content = data;
        });
    }
}
```

If I use `zone` to run the data assignment, then it works as expected, however I feel that it's a bit hacky and I don't really understand why it is not working.

I read that the code might run outside of angular zone but I don't understand why as I'm only using built-in features.

View binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let str of content">
    {{ str }}
</div>
```

Could you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your view binding look like. I also don't see a reason why you would need `zone.run(...)` for this example.

Comment: Me neither, that's why I don't understand why it is not working. I've added the view binding.

Comment: What do you get if you add `<div>{{content | json}}</div>`?

Comment: It doesn't have any affect, unfortunately.

Comment: This means that `this.content = data` doesn't assign any value.

Comment: Actually it does. If I do the following: `log(this.content); this.content = data; log(this.content)` then I see it goes from undefined to the object itself.

Comment: Please try to reproduce in a Plunker. The code you posted doesn't contain the cause of the problem.

Comment: Somehow it is working in a Plunker example. Might it be related to webpack configuration?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that. I'm only using Dart myself.

Comment: would you please provide webpack config? but it realy strange if it is related to webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was neither webpack nor my code but the 3rd party code I used.

I implemented Google login based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538969/2863995) and as you can see it uses a native JS handler - which I think caused the problem. If I put that code into zone.run, then everything works properly. I think the reason is that the handler ran outside of the zone context and that's why the view was not updated.