# angular2-google-login trying to connect to google

Tags: angular, google-signin

I am trying to login with google but when i press the button i get an error , i print the error from AuthService Class and the error i get is: "Could not attach click handler to the element. Reason: element not found"

this is my code:

```
import { Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService, AppGlobals } from 'angular2-google-login';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
class User {
    email: string;
    password: string;
} 

@Component({
    selector: 'cv-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [AuthService, User]
})

export class LoginComponent {
    user: User;
    sub: any;

    constructor(private _auth: AuthService) {
        AppGlobals.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        this.user = new User();


    }
    ngOnInit() {



    }

    signIn() {

        this._auth.authenticateUser(() => {
            console.log("login"); 


        });

    }

    logout() {
        this._auth.userLogout(() => {
            console.log("logout"); 
        });
    }
}
```

html:

```
<h1>Angular2 Social login</h1>
    <button (click)="signIn('google')">google</button>
    <button (click)="logout()">logout</button>
    <div *ngIf="user">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

what i am asking is a little direction or fix of my problem
thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your template file or the relevant bits of it?

Comment: i dont understand what do you need me to share

Comment: I believe @HugoNoro is after `login.component.html`.

Comment: Oh sorry for not being more explicit. Yes the login.component.html

Comment: i added it to the end of my question.. thanks

Comment: It looks like a fault in `angular2-google-login`. Considering there's no tests or usage documentation, it's difficult to confirm without a working system.

Comment: You might be better off looking at this SO question [How to implement SignIn with Google in Angular 2 using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846232/how-to-implement-signin-with-google-in-angular-2-using-typescript)